# Big-O Notation: Why is O(n) + O(log2n) = O(n)? And is my conclusion that reached said question correct?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

I'm working on Big-O Notation for university, and I have some exercises to determine the Big-O and Time Complexity of a code snippet. The code snippet below is what I need to determine the Big-O Notation for:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){

    for(int j = 1; j < 100; j++){

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}

int k = 1;
while(k < n){
    k = k * 2;
}
```

In my work through of the exercise, I determined the first two for loops to be O(n). The while loop is O(log<sub>2</sub>n). I added some comments to the code below to show my thinking.

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){ // This line loops until n times, thus O(n)

    for(int j = 1; j < 100; j++){ // This line loops at a constant 100 times, thus O(1)

        System.out.println("Hello World"); // This line prints once, O(1)
    }
}

// The notations above: O(n) + O(1) + O(1) = O(n)

int k = 1; // This line is used once, thus O(1)
while(k < n){
    k = k * 2; // For every iteration, k is doubled. Thus, we need to find how many iterations, x, is needed until the condition is met. This is 2^x = n. Solve for n we get log2n. Therefore O(log2n) (the 2 would be a subscript)
}

// I'm left with O(n) and O(log2n)
```

I've done some research if O(logn) + O(n) = O(nlogn) but it seems that O(nlogn) only occurs when a logarithmic time complexity happens inside a linear loop. In this case, the while loop is outside of any for loops. My research has also revealed that O(logn) + O(n) != O(nlogn) but rather just O(n).

My questions are: Is my conclusion correct regarding the two notations I found? If so, would this be a O(n) time complexity and why is it O(n) if there is a O(log2n)? If conclusion is not correct, where did I go wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: log(2n) = log(2)+log(n) = log(n). Therefore O(n) + O(log2n) = 2*O(n) = O(n)  (adding or multiplication by a constant is not relevant for O notation. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Do you realise how slowly logarithmic functions grow?

Comment: The final complexity, based on the worst case.

Comment: O(N) grows much faster than O(logN), u can see this in a graph - <search in google for a 'big o notation graph' images>.
That's why it "eats" the O(logN) part when you plus them: O(N) + O(logN) = O(N)

Comment: There is no such thing as *O(log2N)*. This reduces by the laws of Big-O to *O(logN)*.

Comment: There might be some confusion between log2(n) and log(2n). Which ultimately doesn't matter, since O(log_a(b n)) = O(log_c(d n)) for all constants a, b, c, d (assuming a,c > 1 and b,d > 0).

Comment: Because omitting the constant log 2 term, log(n) ≤ n for all n, implying n + log(n) ≤ 2n.